# Is there any way to get a unique device ID in React Native for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to get a unique ID of a device that is always the same even when installing and uninstalling and reinstalling. Is there anything that is accessible anymore to accomodate this requirement?

Device name is now out the window with iOS 16 and it seems like serial number is not possible either. Is there something that can be unique to a device?

My app is not distributed through the app store either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native-device-info, in that there are method called getDeviceToken()  and getUniqueId() try to use that.

getUniqueId() gives you UUID of device.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getdeviceid